# GroupBy makes time index disappear

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

With this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[1,7],[1,9]], index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

i.e.

```
            a  b
2015-01-01  1  1
2015-01-02  1  2
2015-01-03  1  3
2015-01-04  1  5
2015-01-05  1  7
2015-01-06  1  9
```

the fact of using `df = df.groupby(df.b // 4).last()` **makes the datetime index disappear. Why?**

```
   a  b
b      
0  1  3
1  1  7
2  1  9
```

---

Expected result instead:

```
            a  b
2015-01-03  1  3
2015-01-05  1  7
2015-01-06  1  9
```

Comment: Not sure why you expect this, you're effectively generating a new df and index here, the same thing would happen if your index was ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

Comment: @EdChum I edited and wrote the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `groupby` your index always getting from grouping values. For you case you could use `reset_index` and then `set_index`:

```
df['c'] = df.b // 4
result = df.reset_index().groupby('c').last().set_index('index')

In [349]: result
Out[349]: 
            a  b
index           
2015-01-03  1  3
2015-01-05  1  7
2015-01-06  1  9
```